# path position with raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

how can i change path position with raphael js?

it very strange that obvious way not working:

```
var p = paper.path("some path string");

p.attr("fill","red");
p.attr({x:200,y:100});  //not working
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
var p = paper.path("M10 10L90 90L10 90");

p.attr("fill","red");
p.translate(300, 100);
```

Comment: Can i make animation based on translate method?

Comment: Seems like i can: `p.animate({translation: '0 50'}, 1000,'bounce');`

Answer (score 5):

I got it done using something like this:

```
p.attr({path:"M10 10L90 90L10 90"});
```

Answer (score 5):

To move a path in Raphael 2.0+, set or animate the transform attribute using translate ('t'), like this:

```
// animate
someElement.animate({transform: ['t',100,100]}, 1000);

// set
someElement.attr({transform: ['t',100,100]});
```

This overwrites any existing translation. So, this...

```
someElement.animate({transform: ['t',100,100]}, 1000, function(){
  someElement.animate({transform: ['t',50,50]}, 1000);
});
```

... will move down right 100px, then, it'll go back up left 50px, ending 50px down and right from where it started. *(if it's been rotated,  it'll take that rotation into account - use 'T' instead of 't' to ignore past rotation)*

---

If you want it to move based on **relative, not absolute, co-ordinates**, based on where it is now not where it was when it was first translated, you need to get the previous translation co-ordinates and apply them.

This is harder than you might expect. There are two ways that I know of:

1: Store the transform data in `someElement.data()`*:

```
someElement.data('t',[100,100]);
// stuff happens...
var translate = someElement.data('t');
```

2: Get the transform data using `someElement.transform()` then parse the hell out of it, for example*:

```
var transform = someElement.data();
for (var i = transform.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(transform[i][0].toLowerCase() == 't') {
    var translate = [ transform[i][1], transform[i][2] ];
    break;
  }
};
```

*Adjust if you need to distinguish 't' from 'T'

Then, to animate a movement and keep going...

```
someElement.animate({transform: ['t',100,100]}, 1000, function(){
  someElement.animate({transform: ['t',50+translate[0],50+translate[1] ]}, 1000);
});
```

Don't be tempted to use `getBBox()` for this (the [standard way to get Raphael element positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019110/raphael-position) for any type of element). `getBBox()` will include any non-translate movement, like the M move in the path definition.

Comment: Here's another way to move paths where you set an absolute X / Y position you want the path to move to:http://stackoverflow.com/a/15232507/568458

Answer (score 1):

`translate` is absolute, if you need relative postioning, you can use p.attr` to change the "M" parameter

Comment: I think translate is relative according to the doc: _Adds translation by given amount to the list of transformations of the element._